# Websever behind Sonicwall, Gateway Timeout

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, timeout, sonicwall

I am stuck here, I have a Cradlepoint CBA750B in IP-passthrough mode connected to x1 on my Sonicwall NSA220. Behind the Sonicwall I have a webserver on the LAN. I have X1 set to use DHCP to get the WAN IP and is getting the STATIC IP provided my Verizon all well. I followed the wizard for setting up an outward facing server with a custom group (one server on my LAN provides HTTP/IMAP/SMTP). Email works fine externally, I can send and receive all fine and dandy. I cannot get web pages to pull up from an external site though. I dont ever get past "waiting for xxxx...". My Apache Logs are showing the GET requests as expected but the browser never connects. I know the Cradlepoint is setup right because if I directly connect to it I can pull up web pages from external locations just fine. My Sonicwall logs only show and incoming NAT mapping but no return. Any ideas what could cause this?

Thanks,
Nat

Answer (score 0):

Use the packet capture feature on your 220.  It will show the NAT coming in and why/where it's getting dropped trying to go out. [This link](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/capture-traffic-sonicwall-31975.html) shows how to capture all traffic, but I'd reduce it down by adding filters.  It's very easy to add filters to only look for certain ports/IPs but let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look for:

1. Make sure your Sonicwall and even Cradlepoint firewalls are allowing http and https traffic on the port your server is listening to.
2. Verify that your NAT is forwarding HTTP and HTTPS to your server. Both devices have web interfaces and will take the HTTP and HTTPS traffic for them if you don't forward the specific ports you used on your web server.